# Building a plot and correcting visualisation python, pandas, matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[image: plot]

I am building a plot. I have two types of data. Tampstamp column store dates and favorite count stores count of likes. I want to visualise favorite count during the time since posting the tweet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text, not just a screenshot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `timestamp` are strings. Convert it to `datetime` type and `matplotlib\pandas` will give you a nicer x-axis:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
df.plot(x='timestamp',y='favorite_count')
```